# Get Android DhcpInfo connected via Ethernet

Tags: android, networking, wifimanager, android-connectivitymanager

How to get DhcpInfo() (gateway ip, netmask, dns, etc) of android device connected via Ethernet?

I know how to get it if device connected via Wifi and using ACCESS_WIFI_STATE permission:

```
 WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Service.WIFI_SERVICE);
 DhcpInfo dhcp = wifi.getDhcpInfo();
```

But I still not found the way to get it if device connected via ethernet...
Thanks

Answer (score 8):

In your **AndroidManifest.xml** file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

**Your code:**

```
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Service.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

                /* you can print your active network via using below */
                Log.i("myNetworkType: ", connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo().getTypeName());
                WifiManager wifiManager= (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(getApplicationContext().WIFI_SERVICE);


                Log.i("routes ", connectivityManager.getLinkProperties(connectivityManager.getActiveNetwork()).getRoutes().toString());
                Log.i("domains ", connectivityManager.getLinkProperties(connectivityManager.getActiveNetwork()).getDomains().toString());
                Log.i("ip address ", connectivityManager.getLinkProperties(connectivityManager.getActiveNetwork()).getLinkAddresses().toString());
                Log.i("dns address ", connectivityManager.getLinkProperties(connectivityManager.getActiveNetwork()).getDnsServers().toString());



                if(connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo().getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
                    Log.i("myType ", "wifi");
                    DhcpInfo d =wifiManager.getDhcpInfo();
                    Log.i("info", d.toString()+"");
                }
                else if(connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo().getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_ETHERNET) {
/* there is no EthernetManager class, there is only WifiManager. so, I used this below trick to get my IP range, dns, gateway address etc */

                    Log.i("myType ", "Ethernet");
                    Log.i("routes ", connectivityManager.getLinkProperties(connectivityManager.getActiveNetwork()).getRoutes().toString());
                    Log.i("domains ", connectivityManager.getLinkProperties(connectivityManager.getActiveNetwork()).getDomains().toString());
                    Log.i("ip address ", connectivityManager.getLinkProperties(connectivityManager.getActiveNetwork()).getLinkAddresses().toString());
                    Log.i("dns address ", connectivityManager.getLinkProperties(connectivityManager.getActiveNetwork()).getDnsServers().toString());

                }
                else {

                }
```

**Output**
[image]

You can't reach to know whether you are connected via wifi or network using `WifiManager` as `WifiManager` only deals with wifi. You have to use `ConnectivityManager`. I updated the code again where I merged `WifiManager` and `ConnectivityManager` to produce the result that you wanted.

Comment: but do you know how to get gateway/router ip address, netmask, dns setting when device connected via ethernet?

Comment: @WidhaprasaWaliprana connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo().toString()

Comment: I get:

[type: ETHERNET[], state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: (unspecified), extra: (none), roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true, isConnectedToProvisioningNetwork: false]

i don't get gateway/router ip address, netmask, dns

Comment: forgot to tag @uddhav-gautam

Comment: @WidhaprasaWaliprana, if my answer solved your problem, please don't forget to accept this as a valid answer. Thanks.

Comment: think the solution is still not valid, because you dont give answer how to get it if the android device connected via ETHERNET (LAN) not WIFI

Comment: This will only work in API 23+ as ConnectivityManager.getActiveNetwork() was added in that API.

Comment: @UddhavGautam.. In getRoute() what are the IP address are returning? Any idea?